# Printing a pattern to the screen in C

Tags: c

I'm in my first programming course ever and have a few questions about an assignment that we've been given.

I'm trying to print the following pattern to the screen:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

The pattern is supposed to contain 5 rows and each subsequent row has 2 additional asterisks from the row above making roughly a pyramid shape.

I've been working on creating code to do this using `for` loops (this was part of the instructions) and here's what I have so far:

```
int main ()
{
    int row;
    int col;

    for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) //rows
    {
        for (col = 1; col <= row; col++) //columns
        {
            printf_s("*");
        }
        printf_s("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code is that I am not accounting for the required empty spaces to get the alignment correct. With the above current code here's what the output looks like:

```
*
**
***
**** 
*****
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to how to re-write my code to get the correct alignment and the correct number of leading spaces.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The simple solution would be *another* loop to print the spaces.

Comment: "_pyramid_"?  You mean a triangle?

Comment: How many spaces are missing? One in the first row? Two in the second row? Three in the thrird row? Can you see a pattern? What could you do in order to make them not be missing anymore?

Comment: Note that the number of stars should be 1,3,5,7 so you need to calculate that from the row number (`row * 2 - 1`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pascal Triangle like star pattern in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749059/pascal-triangle-like-star-pattern-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is for each row and the inner loop prints a number of asterisks in the row. YOu have omitted to preceded the row with a suitable number of spaces.

If you change the outer loop to the more conventional:

```
for (row = 0; row < 5; row++)
```

It makes the character count arithmetic simpler.

- The inner loop should be *preceded* by another loop to print `4 - row` spaces.
- The asterisk loop needs to print `row * 2 + 1` asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop to print the asterisks but you are not printing out any spaces before that.

And the number of asterisks you print are not correct. For example your output has only 2 `*`s in second line when there should've been 3.

You could do

```
printf("%*s", NUM, "");
```

to print `NUM` spaces instead of using a separate loop.

Something like

```
for (row = 0; row < ROWS ; row++) //rows
{
    printf("%*s", ROWS-1-row, "");
    for (col = 0; col < row*2+1; col++) //columns
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The number of asterisks in each row is one more than double the row number if the row numbering starts from `0`.

`ROWS` represent the number of rows to be printed.

Comment: In the first for loop what is ROWS? Is this a variable and if so how do I declare/initialize it?

Comment: @PatrickMaloney See the last line of my answer. It may be an `int` like `int ROWS=5;` or a macro like `#define ROWS 5`.

Comment: Here's how I've interpreted your instructions:
` {
 int row;
 int col;
 int ROWS = 4;

 

 for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) //rows
 {
  printf("%*s", 5 - 1 - row, "");

  for (col = 0; col < row * 2 + 1; col++) //columns
  {
   printf("*");
  }
 }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
 }
`

Comment: @PatrickMaloney That wasn't very readable but judging by the first line I guess it's correct and the `printf("%*s", 5 - 1 - row, "");` was `printf("%*s", ROWS - 1 - row, "");`.

Comment: Sorry, first time using this site.  Let me try again:
`for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) //rows`
`printf("%*s", 5 - 1 - row, "");`
`for (col = 0; col < row * 2 + 1; col++) //columns`
`printf("*");`

This gives me the correct number of asterisks and what I think is the correct number of leading spaces but it's printing all to a single line.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: As an academic exercise I doubt that using this arcane feature of `printf` would be acceptable since it does not demonstrate mastery of for loops, which is likely the aim of the exercise.  Also the question asks to be "point me in the right direction", not "do it for me".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
r - count of rows
s - increment
i - rows index
j - columns index
start - starting count of *

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,r=4,s,start;
    start = 1;
    s = start*2;

    for (i=0;i<r*s;i+=s)
    {
        for (j=0;j<r*s/2-(i/2)-start;j++) printf(" ");
        for (j=0;j<i+start;j++) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also the question asks to be "point me in the right direction", not "do it for me".

Comment: @Adam Thank you very much. Your code works perfectly but I'm having some difficulty understanding all the components.  Can you start with explaining the variables int i and int j?  I think they represent the rows and columns but am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Print the following shape on the screen

*#                 #*
*#*#             #*#*
*#*#*#         #*#*#*
*#*#*#*#     #*#*#*#*
*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript version, which may help findout the algorithm for C

[image: screenshot]

```
for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
  console.log(" ".repeat(4-i) + "*".repeat(i*2-1))
}
```